# Postgrsql : Insert if not exist else return value

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I want to do something like this.

insert into tb values (c1, c2)
if c2 already in table return c1
else insert data

postgresql version 9.4.24

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I understand but it's the client with this version